# How to eliminate blank space

Tags: php, mysql

I have an input text form but sometimes some forms are not filled with text, but I don't want to generate blank space in my echo page. How can I eliminate this lost space if my input text is not entered in the form.

```
<? echo $rows['info']; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding. Where does this blank space come from?

Comment: Don't ask questions Mike.. it's... it's best if we don't know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use trim:

```
<? echo trim($rows['info']); ?>
```

add the <br />:

```
$info = trim($rows['info']);

if (!isEmpty($info)) {
    echo $info . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: How can I add <br> if the input text is filled out?

Answer (score 3):

```
<? echo trim($rows['info']); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: How can I add <br> if the input text is filled out?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the php `trim()` function.